# Mysql Query return Null in mysql 5.6.12 but runs on mysql 5.5.8

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp

I upgraded my Server from from WAMP2.2 to WAMP2.4. I am struggling while execute the query on mysql-5.6.12.

This query returns `NULL` in mysql-5.6.12 but it successfully ran on Mysql-5.5.8.

***Query:***

```
SELECT DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL SEC_TO_TIME( TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND , NOW( ) , "2013-11-13 15:13:00" ) /2 )HOUR_SECOND )
```

Please any one can tell me, where I did mistake or what is the issue behind it?

Comment: Run `SELECT NOW()` on each version, and check two value is same.

Comment: i guess, it is something related to time settings you have done in your previous WAMP version

Comment: I executed the Query select now() in both versions and the output came as same. What I need to do? {Sorry For my bad English friends}

Comment: both versions have same Time Zone. 
I am using "Asia/Kolkata"

Comment: @PrabuRamS sorry, I guessed it maybe different. I have no idea next step. sorry.

Comment: Thanks Jungsu Heo, tell me your suggestion to upgrade my wamp server if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break your statement down to its parts and build it up again you will notice that the result of this statement is different between MySQL 5.5 and 5.6

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND , NOW( ) , "2013-11-13 15:13:00" ) / 2;
```

If MySQL 5.5 the result is an integer and in 5.6 its a float.
So

```
MySQL 5.5
result is -36221
MySQL 5.6
result is -36221.0000
```

I think its this that is messing up the end result.

If you change your query to

```
SELECT DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL ROUND( SEC_TO_TIME( TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), "2013-11-13 15:13:00" ) / 2 ) ) HOUR_SECOND );
```

You will get the same result on both MySQL 5.5 and MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of you guys. 
Finally I got a Solution. The problem is data type. 
I changed the query

From Old Query:

```
select DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), "2013-11-19 13:00:00")/2) HOUR_SECOND);
```

To New Query:

```
select DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL ceil(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), "2013-11-19 13:00:00"))/2) HOUR_SECOND);
```

Here I used `Ceil()` function

Thanks once again for your support.